# Does shorting this branch disable these resistors?

Tags: resistors, short-circuit

[image]

When I short the branch across the nodes connection R15 and R10 will they be disable, and I only need to calculate R6||R6||R24 + R2?

Comment: What does disable a resistor mean? Where are your resistor reference names on your circuit?

Comment: Oh I mean like would resistor value 15 and resistor value 10 be considered in the circuit if shorted across?

Comment: They are in the circuit whether you short them or not. I think you need to be clear about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you short those nodes, \$R_{15}\$ and \$R_{10}\$ are not "disabled" or ignored when performing the circuit analysis. The short creates a single larger node. In other words, \$R_6||R_3\$ is in series with \$R_{15}||R_{10}\$. Calculating the equivalent resistance: \$R_{eq}=R_2 + [(R_6||R_3)+(R_{15}||R_{10})]||R_{24}\$ Its
Its easiest to see how the short makes a single node in the following schematic of just the inner resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKD7WO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @JakeGinobi Keep in mind that shorting those two **nodes** will not give you the same answer compared to not shorting them. It will only give the same answer if \$\frac{R_6}{R_{15}}=\frac{R_3}{R_{10}}\$, which is not true in this particular case.